# Error with formatting google map api. Cannot view google map embedded with api

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have an embedded map using iframe and want to change to using an api. I've used the code from the google website to test, added the api key, but the map doesn't show on my webpage. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? http://www.lithicsireland.ie/Archaeology_Projects_Irish_Lithic_Landscapes_Chert_Provenancing.html
The code I've used is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapbox'),
        mapOptions);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()"> 
<div class="mapcontainer"><div class="mapbox"></div>
</div>
```

And in css I have:

```
      .mapcontainer {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0em 5%;
    padding: 1em;
    }

    .mapbox {
    float: left;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0em 5%;
    padding: 1em;
    }
```

Comment: There is no div with id="mapbox' on  your page (it has a class of "mapbox").

Comment: I originally had the <div class="mapbox"> as <div id="mapbox">, but it didn't work so I tried <div class....changed it back to  <div id="mapbox"> and still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no div with id="mapbox' on your page (it has a class of "mapbox").

It works if you use getElementsByClassName('mapbox')[0] to get the reference to the map (and give it a reasonable height).

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: {
            lat: -34.397,
            lng: 150.644
        },
        zoom: 8
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementsByClassName('mapbox')[0],
    mapOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yk7yLg9v/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    zoom: 8
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementsByClassName('mapbox')[0],
    mapOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
.mapcontainer {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0em 5%;
  padding: 1em;
}
.mapbox {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0em 5%;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div class="d2 box">
  <ul>
    <li>Lithics Ireland Consultancy</li>
    <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/100271090634486556106" rel="author"> Killian Driscoll</a>

    </li>
    <li>lithicsireland@gmail.com</li>
    <li>Galway, Ireland</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="d2 box">
  <div class="mapcontainer">
    <div class="mapbox"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to use id="mapbox" that works also:

[working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yk7yLg9v/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    zoom: 8
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapbox'),
    mapOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
.mapcontainer {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0em 5%;
  padding: 1em;
}
#mapbox {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0em 5%;
  padding: 1em;
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div class="d2 box">
  <ul>
    <li>Lithics Ireland Consultancy</li>
    <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/100271090634486556106" rel="author"> Killian Driscoll</a>

    </li>
    <li>lithicsireland@gmail.com</li>
    <li>Galway, Ireland</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="d2 box">
  <div class="mapcontainer">
    <div id="mapbox"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've used your second option of <div class="mapcontainer">
    <div id="mapbox"> and changed the css file, but I still don't see the map on the webpage.

Comment: Yes! Thanks, I see the code snippet, but when I change the webpage according to the code snippet, I still can't see the map on the webpage

Comment: I see it on your page in the element explorer in Chrome, it looks like you have issues with your d2 and box css classes.  It is in the lower left hand corner of the page and not very big...

Comment: Thanks, I see it now at the bottom left - unfortunately I am in the middle of changing hosts and my website is now down for some reason: have to figure this out tomorrow....

Comment: I've moved the problematical map to its own box (and changed the names as well) but I can't figure out what is causing the problem (<div class="d1-d3 box"><div class="mapcont"><div class="mapper"></div></div></div>). Should I start this as a new question based on issues with my fluid grid set up, instead of a mapping problem?

Comment: Probably get more useful help that way.